# Dynamically embed application manifest

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I know how to create app.manifest statically from inside Visual Studio. But is there any simple way of dynamically embedding application manifest file to an existing assembly? 

I don't wish to use tools like mt.exe as I can't redistribute them at the client machine.

Comment: If you embed the manifest at build-time, why would you need to distribute mt.exe?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I couldn't find a way to dynamically embed app.manifest to an existing assembly, and surprisingly this question didn't even get a single comment. So, I changed my approach of solving the problem. Now, I am compiling my assembly dynamically (at the client site) and using custom resource containing my custom app.manifest.

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem.